# How to play youtube videos faster in android app

Tags: android, video, youtube

i am trying to play youtube videos in android video view. it's all working fine but my problem is youtube video is taking too much time to buffering and playing, how to resolve this issues. same application working good in IOS. but i am facing this problem only in android. here is my code just check it.

```
public class Videoview extends Activity {
    VideoView videoView;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_VIDEO = "url";
    //private String path= video;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);


        videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_player);  
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Videoview.this, "", "Buffering video pleasewait...", true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true); 
        Videoview();
    }
    private void Videoview()
     {
      try
           { 
          //getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            // getting intent data
            Intent in = getIntent();

            // Get JSON values from previous intent
            String video = in.getStringExtra("Video");

            // Displaying all values on the screen
            TextView lblVideo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.video_label);

            lblVideo.setText(video);

            String path= video;
           // String path= "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/android_book/movie.mp4";
            MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);  
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView); 

            //specify the location of media file
            Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);

            //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView  
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);  
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.requestFocus(); 
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
            {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {                  
                    progressDialog.dismiss();     
                    videoView.start();

                }
        });           


     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.toString());
         finish();
    }              

    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe use the YouTubePlayerView from the API? I've never used it but maybe it will help : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: @Tr4X is it possible to increase the speed by using videoview?

Comment: No idea, that's why I gave you another possible solution